# Google Drive API not listing all company files in domain. Stuck with 30 partial results maximum

Tags: .net, powershell, google-drive-api, google-apps

All, I'm at my wits end and need guidance.  I have been trying for a weeks to leverage a domain delegated service account to get an enumeration of all files and folders owned by all users in our company's Google Drive and Apps, Unfortunately the most I ever get is a list of 30 documents that I know not to all inclusive because none of my user documents are on the list.

However, without corpus on the request I can see the files associated owned by or shared with my personal user account (not the service account).

I've been through all SDK documentation (which is quit poor IMHO) and samples/examples that I can find online and still stuck with this issue.

Trying via both .NET client libraries and PowerShell direct to REST APIs, I get the same result through both Drive v2 and Drive v3.  Still only 30 documents returned.

Here is my snippet from PowerShell

```
#region Gather a list of files for each user
##https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#fields
##https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it
$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files"
$filesCorpus = "DOMAIN"
$filesPageSize = 1000
$filesSpaces = "drive,photos"
#$filesSpaces = "appDataFolder"

$filesQ = ""
#$filesQ = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"

$requestUri = $uri + "?corpus=$filesCorpus&orderBy=createdTime&fields=files%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&spases=$filesSpaces&pageSize=$filesPageSize&q=$filesQ"

##https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#request
#$filesMaxRes = 1000
#$uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"
#$requestUri = $uri + "?corpus=$filesCorpus&orderBy=createdTime&fields=files%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken&maxResults=$filesMaxRes"
#$ContentType = "application/json"

$fileColl = $null;
$fileColl = @( (Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $requestUri -ContentType $ContentType -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $accessToken"}) )
$fileColl.files.count
$fileColl.files | Out-GridView
#endregion
```

And here is the snippet from .NET:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = 
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        //var fileSVC = new DriveService();
        //fileSVC.Files.List();

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest.CorpusEnum blCorpus = 0;
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
        listRequest.Corpus = blCorpus;
        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
```

The API explorer returns the same set of results so while I'm not getting what I expect to see, at least it is consistant across multiple methods.  This makes me think I'm missing something in my request payload.  I thought that perhaps I am missing something for paging but never get a 'nextPageToken' from either the REST API or .NET beyond the 30 items and the 30 still never shows my personal account's owned documents.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance - RRT

Comment: As a debugging aid, try setting your listRequest.PageSize = 10 which should force the nextPagetoken. If it doesn't, that's your problem. If it does, then look in a different direction.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Paging works until 30 items are returned. Then the paging process stops at 30 items. What direction should I look to next?

Comment: Currently you're requesting listRequest.PageSize = 1000; and seeing only 30.  In and of itself, that's not necessarily an issue, depending on what is happening with nextPageToken. Therefore I'm suggesting you do a test with  listRequest.PageSize = 10 to confirm you get <11 items and a valid nextPageToken.

tbh it doesn't sound like a paging issue, but it would be nice to run a simple test to eliminate it.
Requesting 1000 items is potentially bad idea as you are prone to internal Drive timeouts which you then need to handle. It's better to stick to the default 100 and do the required paging.

Comment: Ok, I am confirming that I have already tested PageSize = 10. The result is paged returned and stops after returning the same 30 items.  I'm not sure if it is a limitation with the api or permissions maybe?